# How to remove first character from first line using sed

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, sed

I have three .csv files that are output from saving a query in MS SQLServer. I need to load these files into an Informix database, which requires that tacking on of a trailing delimiter. That's easy to do using sed

`s/$/,/g`

However, each of these files also contains (as displayed by vim, but not ed or sed) an  at the first character position of the first line.

I need to get rid of this character. It deletes as one character using vim's `x` command. How can I describe this character using sed so I can delete it without removing the line.

I've tried `1s/^.//g`, but that is not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
sed -e '1s/^.//' input_file > output_file
```

Or if you'd like to edit the files in-place:

```
sed -ie '1s/^.//' input_file
```

(Edited) Apparently `s/^.//` doesn't quote do it, updated.

Comment: `^\.` will only match a literal `.` at the start of the line, the `g` flag is redundant as is the redirection and most importantly this will perform a substitution on all matching lines not just the first line.

Comment: @sudo_O fixed it =) not sure why I put it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first character on the first line inplace:

```
sed -i  '1s/^.//' file
```

Comment: This still puzzles me. What is the difference (if any) between -e "<sed-commands>" and -e '<sed-commands>' because yours worked.

Comment: Here quoting doesn't make a difference so I'm not sure what you did, quoting is important to the shell for things like variable expansion and globbing.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
sed -i '1s/^.\(.*\)/\1/' file
```

this should remove the first character from the first line. (try it without the `-i` argument first to make sure)

edit: i originally posted the following, which would delete the first character from every line.  upon re-reading the question i realized that isn't quite what was wanted.

```
sed -i 's/^.\(.*\)/\1/' file
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's the first line I want. That byte alignment data is just 1st line/1st char.